# What are the differences between difficulty levels in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between the three New Game options?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28920/whats-the-difference-between-the-three-new-game-options)

In Deus Ex: Human Revolution, what changes as the difficulty level increases? E.g. more enemies, tougher enemies, better AI etc.